# In Google Apps Script, can a timeout be caught with try/catch or does it occur at a higher level?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

So I have some code running off a button click. There are a number of functions, called one after another. In some of them there are calls to REST services. Occasionally, the whole shebang runs over 6 minutes thus hitting the timeout barrier which, unlike the sound-barrier, cannot be broken.

Is the timeout trappable? Can I wrap the most likely offender in a try/catch and have the catch block evaluate at the appropriate moment? Or am I stuck with trying to make things just so incredibly performant that I never hit the wall?

Comment: When the script runtime is over the maximum time of 6 min (G Suite free edition), it cannot be retrieved by try catch. So unfortunately, the max time cannot be over using it. For example, [it's 30 min at G Suite Business](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). How about this? Or although I'm not sure about your script, how about modifying the script by reducing the process costs of each function? Or how about separating the works of the script and running each functions with the time-driven trigger? If these were not useful for your situation, I have to apologize.

Comment: Your comments are appropriate and welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're calling multiple functions, I'd recommend creating a trigger instead using `ScriptApp.newTrigger`, which could be triggered by introducing another function which checks whether or not the script has exceeded the predetermined execution time (if the max is 6, you could set it to be 5 to be safe).

Referring to something like this -

```
// var today = new Date();
// 'today' is declard in the original script

function isTimeUp(today) {
  var now = new Date();
  return now.getTime() - today.getTime() > 30000;
  // 30000 = 30 seconds; this is the threshold limit
  // you are free to setup your own threshold limit
}
```

I've written more on this topic [here](https://script.gs/bypass-script-execution-timeout-programmatically/) where i've used a `.timeBased()` trigger; however, you may use a different kind of trigger altogether.

Comment: It was the most helpful. I think I ended up with something similar but am not in the head space right now.

Comment: If you are the owner of the blog linked above, you should update the comment about runtime limitations. From what I can see in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations), it is 6 minutes for both workspace and free accounts